# tex font error : rectification needed

Tags: fonts, errors

If i use this command:

```
\documentclass[10pt,amssymb]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsmath,fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text}{URW Bookman L}
\begin{document}

Hi man how are u the font is not appearing

\end{document}
```

i get this errror:

```
\par
l.4 \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text}
{URW Bookman L}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
Runaway argument?
Mapping=tex-text
! Paragraph ended before \\setmainfont was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.4 \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text}
{URW Bookman L}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
! Too many }'s.
<recently read> }
l.4 \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text}
{URW Bookman L}
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.4 \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text}{U
RW Bookman L}
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
Overfull \hbox (34.03pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--5
[]\EU1/lmr/m/n/10 URW
[]
Overfull \hbox (25.97pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--5
\EU1/lmr/m/n/10 Book-
[]
Overfull \hbox (18.89pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--5
\EU1/lmr/m/n/10 man
[]
Overfull \hbox (6.25pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--5
\EU1/lmr/m/n/10 L
[]
(./sample.aux)
\openout1 = `sample.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 7.
Class revtex4 Info: Patching LaTeX tabular. on input line 7.
Class revtex4 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 7.
Class revtex4 Info: multicol was not loaded (OK!) on input line 7.
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font) `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font) `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/lmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font) EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font) EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/lmr/m/it --> EU1/lmr/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/lmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/lmss/m/n --> EU1/lmss/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/lmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font) EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `bold'
(Font) EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/lmr/bx/it --> EU1/lmr/bx/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/lmss/bx/n --> EU1/lmss/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/lmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/bx/n on input line 7.
[1] (./sample.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
4478 strings out of 191470
70000 string characters out of 1925444
162455 words of memory out of 1500000
7668 multiletter control sequences out of 10000+200000
3648 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 1200000 for 2000
605 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
29i,4n,26p,296b,114s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,6000p,200000b,15000s
Output written on sample.pdf (1 page).
```

PLease tell me what to do?

Answer (score 6):

Why did you close an open `[` with a `}`?

Try

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{URW Bookman L}
```

instead?